# Timeago PHP generated element not working

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the timeago plugin http://timeago.yarp.com/

It seems to work if the element is generated within the html however if I try to echo it to the page from php it does not work.
Please see my files below: 1.php where you can see the issue of the correct timeago in the "load_out" div and the incorrect value (from php) in the "div2" div; showall.php; there's a basic connect.php file which connects to a database "test" containing a table "comments" - I won't inlcude it here; finally the jquery plugin which I have called timeago2.js. Please see files below:

1.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="timeago2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();

$(".div2").load('showall.php');

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="load_out" style="border:1px solid red">
<abbr class="timeago" title="2014-07-30T20:00:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
</div>
<div class="div2">
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

showall.php

```
<?php
function showPosts() {

@mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("could not connect to mysql");
@mysql_select_db("test")or die("no database");


$me = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($me)){

echo '<abbr class="timeago" title="2014-07-30T20:00:17Z">hi</abbr>';
}
}
return showPosts();
?>
```

timeago2.js:

```
/**
* Timeago is a jQuery plugin that makes it easy to support automatically
* updating fuzzy timestamps (e.g. "4 minutes ago" or "about 1 day ago").
*
* @name timeago
* @version 1.4.1
* @requires jQuery v1.2.3+
* @author Ryan McGeary
* @license MIT License - http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*
* For usage and examples, visit:
* http://timeago.yarp.com/
*
* Copyright (c) 2008-2013, Ryan McGeary (ryan -[at]- mcgeary [*dot*] org)
*/

(function (factory) {
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
// AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
define(['jquery'], factory);
} else {
// Browser globals
factory(jQuery);
}
}(function ($) {
$.timeago = function(timestamp) {
if (timestamp instanceof Date) {
return inWords(timestamp);
} else if (typeof timestamp === "string") {
return inWords($.timeago.parse(timestamp));
} else if (typeof timestamp === "number") {
return inWords(new Date(timestamp));
} else {
return inWords($.timeago.datetime(timestamp));
}
};
var $t = $.timeago;

$.extend($.timeago, {
settings: {
refreshMillis: 60000,
allowPast: true,
allowFuture: false,
localeTitle: false,
cutoff: 0,
strings: {
prefixAgo: null,
prefixFromNow: null,
suffixAgo: "ago",
suffixFromNow: "from now",
inPast: 'any moment now',
seconds: "less than a minute",
minute: "about a minute",
minutes: "%d minutes",
hour: "about an hour",
hours: "about %d hours",
day: "a day",
days: "%d days",
month: "about a month",
months: "%d months",
year: "about a year",
years: "%d years",
wordSeparator: " ",
numbers: []
}
},

inWords: function(distanceMillis) {
if(!this.settings.allowPast && ! this.settings.allowFuture) {
throw 'timeago allowPast and allowFuture settings can not both be set to false.';
}

var $l = this.settings.strings;
var prefix = $l.prefixAgo;
var suffix = $l.suffixAgo;
if (this.settings.allowFuture) {
if (distanceMillis < 0) {
prefix = $l.prefixFromNow;
suffix = $l.suffixFromNow;
}
}

if(!this.settings.allowPast && distanceMillis >= 0) {
return this.settings.strings.inPast;
}

var seconds = Math.abs(distanceMillis) / 1000;
var minutes = seconds / 60;
var hours = minutes / 60;
var days = hours / 24;
var years = days / 365;

function substitute(stringOrFunction, number) {
var string = $.isFunction(stringOrFunction) ? stringOrFunction(number, distanceMillis)
: stringOrFunction;
var value = ($l.numbers && $l.numbers[number]) || number;
return string.replace(/%d/i, value);
}

var words = seconds < 45 && substitute($l.seconds, Math.round(seconds)) ||
seconds < 90 && substitute($l.minute, 1) ||
minutes < 45 && substitute($l.minutes, Math.round(minutes)) ||
minutes < 90 && substitute($l.hour, 1) ||
hours < 24 && substitute($l.hours, Math.round(hours)) ||
hours < 42 && substitute($l.day, 1) ||
days < 30 && substitute($l.days, Math.round(days)) ||
days < 45 && substitute($l.month, 1) ||
days < 365 && substitute($l.months, Math.round(days / 30)) ||
years < 1.5 && substitute($l.year, 1) ||
substitute($l.years, Math.round(years));
var separator = $l.wordSeparator || "";
if ($l.wordSeparator === undefined) { separator = " "; }
return $.trim([prefix, words, suffix].join(separator));
},

parse: function(iso8601) {
var s = $.trim(iso8601);
s = s.replace(/\.\d+/,""); // remove milliseconds
s = s.replace(/-/,"/").replace(/-/,"/");
s = s.replace(/T/," ").replace(/Z/," UTC");
s = s.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)\(\d\d)/," $1$2"); // -04:00 -> -0400
s = s.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)$/," $100"); // +09 -> +0900
return new Date(s);
},
datetime: function(elem) {
var iso8601 = $t.isTime(elem) ? $(elem).attr("datetime") : $(elem).attr("title");
return $t.parse(iso8601);
},
isTime: function(elem) {
// jQuery's `is()` doesn't play well with HTML5 in IE
return $(elem).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() === "time"; // $(elem).is("time");
}
});

// functions that can be called via $(el).timeago('action')
// init is default when no action is given
// functions are called with context of a single element
var functions = {
init: function(){
var refresh_el = $.proxy(refresh, this);
refresh_el();
var $s = $t.settings;
if ($s.refreshMillis > 0) {
this._timeagoInterval = setInterval(refresh_el, $s.refreshMillis);
}
},
update: function(time){
var parsedTime = $t.parse(time);
$(this).data('timeago', { datetime: parsedTime });
if($t.settings.localeTitle) $(this).attr("title", parsedTime.toLocaleString());
refresh.apply(this);
},
updateFromDOM: function(){
$(this).data('timeago', { datetime: $t.parse( $t.isTime(this) ?
$(this).attr("datetime") : $(this).attr("title") ) });
refresh.apply(this);
},
dispose: function () {
if (this._timeagoInterval) {
window.clearInterval(this._timeagoInterval);
this._timeagoInterval = null;
}
}
};

$.fn.timeago = function(action, options) {
var fn = action ? functions[action] : functions.init;
if(!fn){
throw new Error("Unknown function name '"+ action +"' for timeago");
}
// each over objects here and call the requested function
this.each(function(){
fn.call(this, options);
});
return this;
};

function refresh() {
var data = prepareData(this);
var $s = $t.settings;

if (!isNaN(data.datetime)) {
if ( $s.cutoff == 0 || Math.abs(distance(data.datetime)) < $s.cutoff) {
$(this).text(inWords(data.datetime));
}
}
return this;
} 

function prepareData(element) {
element = $(element);
if (!element.data("timeago")) {
element.data("timeago", { datetime: $t.datetime(element) });
var text = $.trim(element.text());
if ($t.settings.localeTitle) {
element.attr("title", element.data('timeago').datetime.toLocaleString());
} else if (text.length > 0 && !($t.isTime(element) && element.attr("title"))) {
element.attr("title", text);
}
}
return element.data("timeago");
}

function inWords(date) {
return $t.inWords(distance(date));
}

function distance(date) {
return (new Date().getTime() - date.getTime());
}

// fix for IE6 suckage
document.createElement("abbr");
document.createElement("time");
}));
```

Comment: You need to run `timeago` when your `load` has returned as the first time you run it there are no elements of `abbr.timeago` in the DOM.

Comment: Have a look at how to run a function on `done` event from `load` http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Hi thanks, I'm a novice and I'm still not that clear what needs to be done. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: OK - read the documentation link here http://api.jquery.com/load/
then run the `jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();` in the `complete` function

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery("time.timeago").timeago(); 
});
```

important `<time>` span!

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z" title="July 17, 2008">8 years ago</time>
```

which yields: 8 years ago. As time passes, the timestamps will automatically update